# Objects are not valid as a React child. found: object with keys { .... If you meant to render a collection for children, use an array instead

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I am trying to display an array of object in a react-table and I am getting this error: Objects are not valid as a React child (found: object with keys... If you meant to render a collection of children, use an array instead. where is the problem?

I added prop-types and i am only rendering if I know for sure that it is an array and I am still getting this error.

```js
import React from 'react'
import ReactTable from 'react-table'
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const RegularReactTable = ({data, columns, classNames}) =>{
    const d = [...data]
    console.log('d',d)
    return (
        <ReactTable 
            data = {Array.isArray(d)? d: []}
            columns={columns}
            // turn this to true to see the effect
            showPagination ={false}
            pageSize = {d.length }
            className={classNames}
        />
    )
}

RegularReactTable.propTypes ={
    data: PropTypes.array,
    columns: PropTypes.array,
    classNames: PropTypes.string
}

export default RegularReactTable
```

columns format: [{Header: 'something', accessor:'someElse'},...]
data format:[{someElse: 'SomeValue', ...}, ...]
Note: the **columns'** *accessors* correspond to one of keys in the **data's** array single object

(can't actually post the real data)

this is supposed to be simple but i am getting an error

Comment: can you share the data structure?

Comment: give me a minute

Comment: Just include some sample data with the same structure as your real data and that still reproduces the problem.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I cannot reproduce the same error because this has been working throughout the project expect just this time. I was wondering if there is someone who run in the same problem and how to they debugged this

Comment: @BlaiseIradukunda If you can't provide us data that reproduces the problem, there won't be any way for us to help you with the issue if this same code works most of the time. We need to be able to see what causes it to not work.

Comment: @RyanCogswell I understand. I just also located the issue and I am able to reproduce it so let me share the answer

Comment: One of the accessor 's value was a string with length 0. I reproduced the error with some random data. Here is the link to the code that doesn't work [code that doesn't work](https://codesandbox.io/s/r4lxx7l81q) and another one that works [works](https://codesandbox.io/s/1vpm92kj43)

Answer (score 1):

In the event someone runs into this in the future, I was getting this error when one of my columns accessor was blank.  I had a "spacer" column in place with no accessor which caused this issue.